# Lexicon LXP Bug in Ableton Live 8

Tags: plug-ins, bugs, ableton-live, reverb

My lexicon LXP plug-ins have started to bug out in the most frustrating way and i don't know what to do about it. Every time i bounce out of ableton and i return to the sequencer from the export audio window the plugs immediately feedback to infinity and destroy my ears! Also when i check the audio i have just exported it has the distortion all over it.

It's like as soon as anything runs through the plugs they feed 100% back into themselves. It makes no sense to me. I've tried reinstalling but nothing. If i close Live and re-open sometimes it will be okay for about 5 minutes then return to bugging out. Yet to try them in another DAW

Anyone have a similar problem or can offer advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried contacting support? Or looking in the support forums?

What about track routings? Do you have any routing going on that could lead to a feedback loop, or does it happen in clean/new projects as well?

The quickest way to try it in another DAW is to download REAPER.

Comment: Not yet, wanted to hit up SSD first as they usually offer the best and fastest advice

Comment: What about track routing and new projects?

Comment: It's not a routing problem. I thought for a while that it could be a hidden feedback routing i had set up but its not. It's happening on new, blank projects. Just went to the support section of Lexicon and there's nothing on it.

Comment: I'll try it in Pro Tools tonight. On a tight deadline and havent got time to troubleshoot

Comment: Turns out it happens when you change the sample rate of a project. Well it's not that black and white but it seems to trigger it when i do so at least i can attempt to avoid it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you found out what was causing it!